# dynamically getting reply from ajax/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have created application where user enters `arabic` text , I convert it to `english` [Transliteration].
This happens when user click the button.

I want it to convert dynamically. I mean when user enters any character, it should instantly perform Transliteration for entered text, as and when user keep entering the text, Transliteration should be appended.

I have used ajax which takes user input and post it to php script for Transliteration. Reply from script I display in resulting box.

Here is how I perform action for `button click` event

```
    $( "#en2ar" ).click(function() {
            //var cat = $("#cats option:selected").html();
//          alert(test);
            var english = document.getElementById("english").value;
            //alert (arabic)
            en2ar(english);
            return false;
            });

        function en2ar(english)
        {               
            var xmlhttp;
            arabic.value = '';
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }           
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                //document.getElementById("old-records").innerHTML = "";                
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    var div2 = document.getElementById("arabic");
                                div2.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("POST","processAra.php");          
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.send('arabic=' + english + '&type=' + 'en' ) ;          
            //alert(arabic);
        }
```

Comment: What's the problem? Run your code in the `keyup` handler for the input field.

Comment: Why don't you use `$.ajax()` instead of all that verbose Javascript?

Comment: you can use keyup function

Comment: @Barmar: thanks, I took it as much complex job, `keyup` I did not think of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#english").keyup(function() {
        var english = $("#english").val();
            //alert (arabic)
            en2ar(english);
            return false;     
});
```

you can use key up function .

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
 $( "#en2ar" ).click(function() {
```

use

```
 $( "#en2ar" ).keyup(function() {
```

which will get the text whenever user will write some text.

Comment: `#en2ar` is a button, not the input field.

Comment: Replace that #en2ar to whatever the id u are using for the input field... Though this will consume lot of your bandwidth... So you can use blur instead... This will convert only when the user remove focus from the input field ... Though this totally depends upon your requirement